# Can't place order after migration data from Magento 1 to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4, place-order

When I try place order, it show "Please choose a valid discount amount."
[image: 2.3.4]

Comment: check the error log ...

Comment: Thank @MohitPatel, I have checked log but there are no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section responsible for that error looks like

```
        // Check if discount amount not negative
        if ($this->hasDiscountAmount()) {
            if ((int)$this->getDiscountAmount() < 0) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Please choose a valid discount amount.'));
            }
        }
```

Check your cart rules after migration cause this error is thrown when applied discount amount is less than 0.

Comment: Thank you! I found the issue is I have a Catalog Price Rule have  Discount Amount is "-12".